# questions about Hyperledger composer-rest-server

Tags: hyperledger-composer

Bus error occurs when I run composer-rest-server, why?Thanks

```
zcy@ubuntu:~$  composer-rest-server -c admin@foodsupplychain -n always
Discovering types from business network definition ...
Bus error
```

Answer (score 0):

You can run `stopFabric.sh` and `teardownFabric.sh` and also delete all the network card and retry. I think it should work for you.

Comment: The main reason is the grpc version and the composer-rest-server version.